# How to see this function is supported in the open ball?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\Delta$ be the operator $\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j^2}$. Let $s$ be a positive integer. Then it follows from Theorem 7.1.22 in Hormander's book that $(- \Delta)^s$ has a parametrix $E$.
Parametrix is defined to be a distribution such that
$$
(-\Delta)^s E = \delta + \omega
$$
for some $\omega$, a $C^{\infty}$ function in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Theorem 7.1.22 further states that $E$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus  \{0\}$.

Apparently this $E$ is supported in the open unit ball... This is stated during the proof of Lemma 7.6.3 which I am trying to go through. If someone could give me a hint on how I can see this, it would be appreciated!

Comment: From the definitions you've listed, it is unclear what relationship $E$ has with $(-\Delta)^s$

Comment: fixed the typo. thank you

Comment: Thanks! Since $\omega$ is arbitrary it seems like it was chosen to have the property of having support on the unit ball. There is no derived property here.

Comment: The theorem only guarantees the existence of $E$ (and of smooth $\omega$)... how can one just choose so that $E$ is supported in the open unit ball?

Comment: Simply define $$E = K + K\star \left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{1-||x||_2^2}\right)\cdot\chi_{||x||_2<1}\right)$$ where $K$ is the fundamental solution of $(-\Delta)^s$. It is not so difficult..